# How do i use a for loop to loop every argument into newDate?

Tags: javascript

I have a timeMachine function that takes in 5 parameters and tells you what day it is after the time you entered. But instead of writing newDate.setDate(dateObject.getDate()+daysLater); i want to use a for loop that loops over the arguments' length and logs the inputs into newDate.

```
    var timeMachine=function(yearsLater,monthsLater,daysLater,hoursLater,minutesLater) {
        var dateObject=new Date();
        var newDate=new Date();
        newDate.setDate(dateObject.getDate()+daysLater);
        newDate.setMonth(dateObject.getMonth()+monthsLater);
        newDate.setYear(dateObject.getFullYear()+yearsLater);
        newDate.setHours(dateObject.getHours()+hoursLater);
        newDate.setMinutes(dateObject.getMinutes()+minutesLater);
        console.log(newDate);
    }
    timeMachine()
```

Comment: Are you willing to use a 3rd party library to accomplish the same functionality?

Comment: @PeterWagener I haven't learn all of javascript yet and barely know any 3rd library. But sure!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't using a `for` loop, but I'd suggest using [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) for any date-based manipulation.  Speaking from personal experience, time manipulation is easy to mess up.

Moment already has this sort of "timeMachine()" functionality built in.  For instance:

```
var futureMoment = moment()
        .add(yearsLater, 'years')
        .add(monthsLater, 'months')
        .add(daysLater, 'days')
        .add(hoursLater, 'hours')
        .add(minutesLater, 'minutes');

console.log(futureMoment.format());  // <<== get a formatted string
console.log(futureMoment.toDate());  // <<== 'toDate' gets the native Date object
```

It also has [copious documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs), and good plugins for added functionality.  If you add [moment-parseformat](http://gr2m.github.io/moment-parseformat/), you can easily parse most real-world Date strings (i.e. "November 20th, 2015" or "11/20/15" or "2015/11/20", etc) into Moment objects.

Basically, don't do this yourself unless you really need the bare bones functionality.  Standing on the shoulders of giants is much easier.

Comment: thank you for the advices, one more thing i must ask: how do i change parse the real-world date strings in vanilla javascript?

Comment: @Firefalcon1155 meaning doing something like `new Date("11/20/2015")`?  It's inconsistent across different browsers.  See http://dygraphs.com/date-formats.html for some examples.

Comment: no, i mean instead of the output being "Fri Jan 06 2017  GMT-0800 (PST)", i want it to be like "January 06, 2017"

Comment: Try `moment.calendar()`. See the docs for more flexible options.